# Relation between quotient stacks and quotient sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quotient-spaces, algebraic-stacks

I am studying stacks and I am experiencing some troubles understanding quotient stacks. If I have a scheme $X$ where a group scheme acts $G$ (let's suppose that everything is defined over an algebraically closed field of char $0$),  I don't quite understand what is the relationship (if there is any) between the quotient stack $[X/G]$ and the quotient sheaf $X^{\bullet}/G^{\bullet}$ where the notation $\bullet$ means the functor of points. In particular, what happens when the action is free and transitive?

Thank you for your time, I am a noobie in this realm.

Comment: If you have a free group action then there is no difference between the ordinary quotient and the stack quotient. The point is that the stack quotient "remembers" the stabiliser groups. You might want to think about the other extreme, namely what happens when you quotient by a trivial action.

Comment: Hi @ZhenLin , thank you for your comment. Can you give some references for that sort of  results?